# SQL Server Credit, Debit and Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as following.

```
Name|   Date        |   Debit   |   Credit
-------------------------------------------
A   |   02.02.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00
A   |   03.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00
A   |   04.02.2020  |   0,00    |   30,00
A   |   05.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00
A   |   06.02.2020  |   40,00   |   0,00
A   |   07.02.2020  |   50,00   |   0,00
A   |   08.02.2020  |   15,00   |   0,00
A   |   09.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00
A   |   10.02.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00
A   |   11.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00
A   |   12.02.2020  |   0,00    |   50,00
A   |   13.02.2020  |   0,00    |   60,00
A   |   14.02.2020  |   20,00   |   15,00

B   |   20.01.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00
B   |   21.01.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00
B   |   22.01.2020  |   40,00   |   0,00
B   |   23.01.2020  |   0,00    |   100,00
B   |   24.01.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00
B   |   25.01.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00
B   |   26.01.2020  |   0,00    |   10,00
B   |   27.01.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00
```

I want to create a "view" with this table. Firstly all the "credits" will be added to each other according to "name". Then, from the total of "credit" "debit" will be subtracted. The value obtained here will be written to the "balance" column in first date. Then from this, the values on "debit" column will be subtracted in order and written to the "balance" column in today's date.

The "view" I want to obtain is given in the following figure.

```
Name|   Date        |   Debit   |   Credit  |   Balance |   Credit Total
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
A   |   02.02.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00    |   145,00  |   155,00
A   |   03.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   125,00  |
A   |   04.02.2020  |   0,00    |   30,00   |   125,00  |
A   |   05.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   105,00  |
A   |   06.02.2020  |   40,00   |   0,00    |   65,00   |
A   |   07.02.2020  |   50,00   |   0,00    |   15,00   |
A   |   08.02.2020  |   15,00   |   0,00    |   0,00    |
A   |   09.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   -20,00  |
A   |   10.02.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00    |   -30,00  |
A   |   11.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   -50,00  |
A   |   12.02.2020  |   0,00    |   50,00   |   -50,00  |
A   |   13.02.2020  |   0,00    |   60,00   |   -50,00  |
A   |   14.02.2020  |   20,00   |   15,00   |   -70,00  |

B   |   20.01.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00    |   100,00  |   110,00
B   |   21.01.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   80,00   |
B   |   22.01.2020  |   40,00   |   0,00    |   40,00   |
B   |   23.01.2020  |   0,00    |   100,00  |   40,00   |
B   |   24.01.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   20,00   |
B   |   25.01.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00    |   10,00   |
B   |   26.01.2020  |   0,00    |   10,00   |   10,00   |
B   |   27.01.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00    |   0,00    |
```

I can do this in "mvc" as follows:

```
var creditTotal = Model.Sum(x => x.Credit);

foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Date))
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Date</td>
        <td>@item.Debit</td>
        <td>@item.Credit</td>
        <td>@creditTotal - item.Debit</td>
    </tr>
    creditTotal = creditTotal - item.Debit;
}
```

But it will be much better if I can do it in SQL View.

Is there any way to do this in SQL view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(credit) over (partition by name) -
        sum(debit) over (partition by name order by date)
       ) as balance,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name order by date) = 1
             then sum(credit) over (partition by name)
        end) as credit_total
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but this returned an error: Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

And and when I delete "order by date" it writes the total balance in all columns as follows.

```
Name|   Date        |   Debit   |   Credit  |   Balance |   Credit Total
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
A   |   02.02.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |   155,00
A   |   03.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |
A   |   04.02.2020  |   0,00    |   30,00   |   -70,00  |
A   |   05.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |
A   |   06.02.2020  |   40,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |
A   |   07.02.2020  |   50,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |
A   |   08.02.2020  |   15,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |
A   |   09.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |
A   |   10.02.2020  |   10,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |
A   |   11.02.2020  |   20,00   |   0,00    |   -70,00  |
A   |   12.02.2020  |   0,00    |   50,00   |   -70,00  |
A   |   13.02.2020  |   0,00    |   60,00   |   -70,00  |
A   |   14.02.2020  |   20,00   |   15,00   |   -70,00  |
```

Each row needs to be calculated differently.